# Web.config Error:cannot duplicate rule name

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I have deployed node.js app to iis using iisnode.When I browse my app,I see config error as follows 
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'node'

I suspect web.config is loaded twice to iis. I see the folder under C:/Program Files/iisnode/www is where source files are there. This is loaded twice
I have attached pics for clear understanding
[image][image]

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
    </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
     </handlers> 
     <rewrite> 
       <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to Prod HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="infrc">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: move the application folder to another new folder or drive.

Comment: Thanks Jalpa the error disappeared

Comment: please mark the post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the application folder to another new folder or drive.

Regards,
Jalpa

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old issue. Try this:

- close Visual Studio
- remove into your solution folder .vs folder (it is hidden)
- restart your Visual Studio

more than 12 yrs